# Run command SQL query on joomla database to jos_content table to change catid number for specific dates

Tags: sql, joomla, command

my question is quite simple and easy,, and it has to do with the syntax on a SQL query,

I want to run a SQL query BUT I dont know what command to use on the PHPMyAdmin cause i m not very familiar with the sql syntax.

Problem:

Imagine a table named jos_content that among others columns has a column named catid and a column named created.
So on these two columns i want to play. 
So i want to change all rows with catid 162 change to 255 AND that are created from 01/09/2014 till today... 
Bear in mind the created column has data for example like 2015-04-20 09:09:28 ,, I dont know if you can understand the question

Target
I need the full sql command and syndax to achieve automatically and change all rows catid number from this date till today, instead of changing one by one each row.

please some help guys,
Thank you in advance

Comment: That is a really basic query. If you are so unfamiliar with SQL, maybe you should not play with data phpMyAdmin at all.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: be very careful on your data. Perform a backup first. You're the only one responsible on what you're doing. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE #__content
SET catid = 255
WHERE catid = 162
AND created  > '2014-09-01'
```

Did I tell you to be very careful?